# File uploads in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dropzone

I'm just starting out with Laravel and trying to get file uploads working using [Dropzone JS](https://www.dropzonejs.com/). I can upload files successfully, but they're landing in `app/Http/Controllers`, where they're not then publicly accessible.

It seems to be treating this directory as the root, so if I specify /uploads as the folder then they'll go in `app/Http/Controllers/uploads` (which is obviously no good either). Using `..`s doesn't seem to have any effect.

This is my store method for the file uploads:

```php
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$storeFolder = '';
if ( ! empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;
    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
}
```

I've also tried a number of other methods I found (below) but I get 500 errors in Chrome's element inspector with those.

**From official docs**

```php
$path = $request->file('file')->store('uploads');
```

**From a tutorial I found**

```php
$file = $request->file('file');
$destinationPath = '/';
$file->move($destinationPath,$file->getClientOriginalName());
```

**From another tutorial**

```php
$uploadedFile = $request->file('file');
$filename = time().$uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName();
Storage::disk('local')->putFileAs(
    '/'.$filename,
    $uploadedFile,
    $filename
);
```

The current method seems fine but just needs to store files in public/uploads.

Comment: have you run `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta I have not. Quick Google looks like this creates a symlink, which is a pretty good idea actually, though seems a little hacky?

Comment: yes it will create a storage path to your public directory

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta Thanks for your suggestion - this would probably be a good alternative fix if not for the accepted answer.

Comment: Have you looked at using Laravel functions? [file uploads in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem#file-uploads)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this path instead:

```
$targetPath = public_path().'/uploads/';
```

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest making a perfect route for our storage path so when someone adds hostname/storage it will not show your directory to someone only files can be accessible

```
Route::get('storage/{filename}', function ($filename)
{
    $path = storage_path('public/' . $filename);

    if (!File::exists($path)) {
        abort(404);
    }

    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

    return $response;
});
```